# Auto-Completion for Panda3d in PyCharm

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, panda3d

Does auto-completion for the Panda3d library working with PyCharm? It seems PyCharm cannot automatically create the Python skeletons for this library. I would also be happy if I could at least manually define those stubs in PyCharm.

Any ideas how to tell PyCharm what Python modules and classes are there in a "binary" library?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked just selecting in Settings > Project Interpreter the panda python interpreter (python.exe, not ppython.exe.).

If you wanna use ppython.exe you have to rename to something starting with "python" like pythonpanda.exe, since Pycharm only considers an interpreter something that starts with "python". Anyway, ppython and python are supposed to be the same.

**EDIT**

Another thing that can make it work, is using another python interpreter (the standard, virtualenv, whatever) and placing a path file in a folder within the PYTHONPATH.

In other words:

- Create a text file named panda3d.pth
- Write two lines

path\to\pandafolder
path\to\pandafolder\bin

- Save it in the site-packages of your python interpreter
- Configure Pycharm to use this interpreter

Comment: Does the panda interpreter recognize normal python built-ins? for example "True". Make sure you added the right intepreter, and then you activated it. You can check the logs as well in Help > Show log in explorer